# html5 canvas draw border with specified color based on select input

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a colored border in a HTML5 canvas element where the color of the border is based on the selected value of a select input element.

```
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="">Choose color</option>
    <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
    <option value="000000">Black</option>
</select>
```

How do I go about and do this in javascript? How to catch the value of the selected item and instantly change the bordercolor on the fly on the canvas?

Comment: Does the border must be "HTML border" or have to be drawn inside the canvas using drawing calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/ywe4roox/4/).

**HTML**

```
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="">Choose color</option>
    <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
    <option value="000000">Black</option>
</select>

<canvas id="display"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
$( "#color" ).change(function() {
        drawRectangle($(this).val());
});

function drawRectangle(color) {
    var c=document.getElementById("display");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
    ctx.strokeStyle="#" + color;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick in just a few lines of code :-) Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are looking for `CSS` border:

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value) {
    myCanvas.style.borderColor = '#' + this.value;
  }
});
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: solid 10px #000000;
}
```

```html
<select name="color" id="color">
  <option value="">Choose color</option>
  <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
  <option value="000000">Black</option>
</select>
<br>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

If you want it to do `canvas` way:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 7;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();

document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.value) {
        context.strokeStyle = '#' + this.value;
        context.stroke();
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="">Choose color</option>
    <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
    <option value="000000">Black</option>
</select>
<br>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick friend, use JQuery to fire an event on change of the select box, get the value of the drop down, and use JQuery to manipulate the CSS rules of that div.

Happy coding!

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <select name="color" id="color">
          <option value="">Choose color</option>
          <option value="ff0000" selected = "selected">Red</option>
          <option value="000000">Black</option>
      </select>


      <div id = "change-div">
        some cool content here!!
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>

  <script>
      $('#color').change(function() {
        var color = $('#color');
        var selected = color.val();
        console.log('The Selected value is: ' + selected);
        $('#change-div').css('border-color', selected);
        $('#change-div').css('border-width', '5px');
        $('#change-div').css('border-style', 'solid');
      });
  </script>
```